# SBT: Cannot publish to Apache Archiva

Tags: scala, maven, sbt, archiva

Error message:

```
   java.io.IOException: Access to URL 
   http://maven.company.com/repository/internal/com/company/
   project_2.10/0.0.3/project_2.10-0.0.3.pom was
   refused by the server: Unauthorized
```

Running Apache Archiva 1.4-M4(latest), I am able to upload via the web interface, but not via SBT.

Using these settings in SBT:

```
 publishTo := Some("company releases" at "http://maven.company.com/repository/internal"),
   credentials += Credentials(
     "company Maven Repository",
          "maven.company.com",
          "username",
          "password"
        ),
   publishMavenStyle := true,
   publishArtifact in Test := false,
   pomIncludeRepository := { _ => true },
   // .. some xml with author details
 }
```

All details, including username, password and urls are correct.

Comment: any logs in archiva.log file regarding authz? Are you able to add some debug in sbt tool to be sure user/password are forwarding?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Security Realm is important to Ivy. It's like the only dependency manager that requires you to use a valid Security realm.  I believe for apache archiva it's "Repository Archiva Managed".   You can check by trying to do your own HTTP request to Archiva and see what Realms it tells you it supports.

Here's code which attempts to detect security realms:  https://github.com/sbt/sbt-pom-reader/blob/2b515b58739ef7bdfad8f98248e901db8e140892/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/sbt/pom/MavenHelper.scala#L212-L221

**Update**:
The realm looks like: "Repository Archiva Managed internal Repository". If you publish to other repos, replace "internal" with the name of the repo.

once you determine the security realm, you want to update your build as follows:

```
  credentials += Credentials(
      "Repository Archiva Managed internal Repository",  // Or whatever you detect as the security realm
      "maven.company.com",
      "username",
      "password"
    ),
```

Comment: Anytime. It's the most common error when trying to publish, but the hook into Ivy to improve the error message is like impossible (static methods), or else I'd have tried to patch it already.